# Converting an equation to another form using sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

I have such a problem: I have an expression like `x ** 3 - x ** 2 + x - 5 = 0`. I need to convert it to the form `x = g(x)`, such as `x = root(x ** 2 - x + 5, 3)`.

Can sympy do this? If so, how? Thank you for your informative answer.

Comment: Since `sympy` operates in Python, it can't use `=` as algebraic equality.  Instead you use an `Eq` relation.  I believe this is discussed carefully in the `sympy` introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `x**3` term with `y**3` and solve for `y`:

```
In [26]: lhs = x ** 3 - x ** 2 + x - 5                                                                                                         

In [27]: lhs                                                                                                                                   
Out[27]: 
 3    2        
x  - x  + x - 5

In [28]: lhs.subs(x**3, y**3)                                                                                                                  
Out[28]: 
   2        3    
- x  + x + y  - 5

In [29]: y1, y2, y3 = solve(lhs.subs(x**3, y**3), y)                                                                                           

In [30]: Eq(x, y3)                                                                                                                             
Out[30]: 
       ____________
    3 ╱  2         
x = ╲╱  x  - x + 5
```

Comment: Thank you, but how did you know that you need exactly 3 solution? This is a common example, in a real problem there may be another equation, the solution that I need is not always in 3rd place

Comment: Now I just find a solution from the list with the smallest length of the string representation (in the cases I checked, the solution I need is much shorter than the others)

Comment: The problem you have posed does not have a unique solution so I've shown code that arbitrarily gives the solution you said you wanted. If you want to ask about how to do this "in general" then you will need to define the class of problems more precisely.